# Select item from a drop down list, remove item from list as a value then update a total

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I am trying to use asp.net and C# 
I want to create a variable that has a given value of 10.
lets call this variable pool
I then want to be able to select a number between 1 and 10 from a dropdownlist.

Lets say i select 5 from the ddl
Then 5 should be subtracted from the pool which would leave pool displaying 5.

If i want to go back and select another number from the dropdown list I want to be able to only see the numbers that I can subtract from pool.
I.E i cant choose 6 as there is only 5 left in the pool. 
Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it that hard?

The explanation as per the code comment below

.aspx

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="sm" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="up" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        My Pool : <asp:Label ID="lbl" runat="server" Text="10"></asp:Label><br />
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hf" runat="server" Value="10" />
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddl" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Check
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        // Variable
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Count");

        // Loop
        for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
            dt.Rows.Add(i);

        // Bind to Drop Down
        ddl.DataSource = dt;
        ddl.DataTextField = "Count";
        ddl.DataValueField = "Count";
        ddl.DataBind();

        // Dispose
        dt.Dispose();
    }
}


protected void ddl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Variable
    int myPool = 0;
    int mySelectedValue = 0;
    int result = 0;
    int dropDownValue = 0;
    bool isInteger = false;

    // Parse Integer
    int.TryParse(hf.Value, out myPool);
    int.TryParse(ddl.SelectedValue, out mySelectedValue);

    // Set Result
    result = myPool - mySelectedValue;

    // Set to Hidden Value
    hf.Value = result + "";
    lbl.Text = result + "";

    foreach (ListItem item in ddl.Items)
    {
        // Reset
        isInteger = false;
        dropDownValue = 0;

        // Parse Drop Down Value
        isInteger = int.TryParse(item.Value, out dropDownValue);

        // Check
        if (isInteger)
        {
            // Ensure is not less than 0, If less than 0 disabled the selected value
            if ((result - dropDownValue) < 0)
                item.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I have just started with C# and I have come from the shallows. Really appreciate it! You write very clear and concise code